# Converting From MVC Razor C# to MVC Razor VB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am converting one MVC C# Project to MVC VB. I am getting error at this point

```
<input name = "recipients" type="text" Class="form-control" 
      value="@ViewBag.Email" @(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled"  null) />
```

How to convert this to MVC VB 
Error messages 
== expression expected
null is not declared
? Character cannot be used.

Here is the code

```
<div Class="col-sm-12">
    <div Class="form-group">
        <button Class="btn btn-default" id="get-my-email- address">@Resources.Resource.Graph_GetEmailAddress_Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
    }
<div Class="col-sm-12">
<label for="user-email-address">@Resources.Resource.Graph_GetEmailAddress_Results_Label</label>
<pre name = "user-email-address" >@ViewBag.Email</pre>
</div>

<h2>@Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Heading</h2>
<p>@Html.Raw(Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Instruction)</p>
@(Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Home"))
{
<div Class="col-sm-12">
        <div Class="form-group">
            <label  for="recipients">@Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Recipients_Label</label>
            <input name = "recipients" type="text" Class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Email" @(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled"  null) />
        </div>
        <div Class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">@Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Subject_Label</label>
            <input name = "subject" type="text" Class="form-control" value="@Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Subject_Text @Resources.Resource.App_Name_Short" @(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled"  null) />
        </div>
        <div Class="form-group">
            <button Class="btn btn-default @(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled" : null)">@Resources.Resource.Graph_SendMail_Button</button>
            <input name = "email-address" value=@ViewBag.Email type="hidden" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
   <div Class="col-sm-12">
  <p Class="@(ViewBag.Message == null ? "hidden" : null)">@Html.Raw  (ViewBag.Message)</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Maybe if you were to show us the actual code that generates the error and what the error message is we might have some chance of helping.  Otherwise, we'd need to be psychic to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the " : "  for the "else" in @(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled" **HERE** null) ?? should be:

```
@(ViewBag.Email == null ? "disabled" : null)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. What you have suggested is right but '@(ViewBag.Email == null ?' gives message 'null is not decleared' for '?' character cannot be used here. This code works file in cshtml but in in vbhtml it does not work. I know '==' is not Razor VB operator but I am confused in 'null ?' part. Rest of the project I managed to convert into MVC VB. This a view in project available on Microsoft Graph APi site and most of the examples for this API are in MVC C# so I decided to convert into MVC VB

Comment: Im not a big VB guy, but what that line is essentially saying is:
if (ViewBag.Email == null) "disabled"; else null; If you just remove null maybe and replace it with '  ' that might work?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I changed like this  ' if@(ViewBag.Email = "" OrElse "disabled")endif  ' Now at least design time error have gone but I need to run and test the effect. I will do it in couple of days.